# How do I move a canvas 3D rendering to the background of a webpage in next.js?

Tags: css, reactjs, canvas, next.js, react-three-fiber

I have a next.js app that currently looks like this:
[image]

I have a `hero` component being loaded into a layout and as you can see, it's a `react-three/fiber` `canvas` rendering of a 3D terrain which I got from here https://github.com/ChristianOConnor/linear-vaporwave-react-three-fiber-typescript.

The problem is that the `canvas` is placed IN FRONT OF the text that is supposed to be in front of the `canvas`. This is the same webpage with the `canvas` component removed.
[image]

The "⚡️ Originally inspired by the..." text is supposed to go IN FRONT OF the `canvas`.

This is what the css looks like for the canvas:
[image]

This is what the css looks like for the "⚡️ Originally inspired by the..." text:
[image]

This is the relevant code in the `index.tsx` file:

```
const Scene = () => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {!mounted ? null : (
        <Canvas
          dpr={Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2)}
          linear
          antialias
        >
          <React.Suspense fallback={null}>
            <color attach="background" args={["#000000"]} />
            <fog attach="fog" args={["#000000", 1, 2.5]} />
            <OrbitControls attach="orbitControls" />
            <PerspectiveCamera
              makeDefault
              position={[0, 0.06, 1.1]}
              fov={75}
              near={0.01}
              far={20}
            />
            <Light />
            <Landscape />
          </React.Suspense>
        </Canvas>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="hero min-h-screen bg-base-200">
      <div className="label-container">
        <p className="label">
          ⚡️ Originally inspired by the{" "}
          <a href="https://linear.app/releases/2021-06">
            2021 Linear release page
          </a>
        </p>
        <p className="label">
          ✨ Reverse-engineered and recreated by{" "}
          <a href="https://twitter.com/MaximeHeckel">@MaximeHeckel</a> with
          React-Three-Fiber
        </p>
        <p className="label">
           How I built this?{" "}
          <a href="https://blog.maximeheckel.com/posts/vaporwave-3d-scene-with-threejs/">
            Building a Vaporwave scene with Three.js
          </a>{" "}
          (Three.js only)
        </p>
      </div>
      <Scene />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

So how do I get the `canvas` to sit behind the "⚡️ Originally inspired by the..." text?

Comment: Have you tried altering z-index on the canvas's parent?

Comment: Yes, that actually worked. I already knew I could do this but isn't that bad practice for some reason? I found a few other posts where people solved similar problems this way and everyone seems to down vote those answers. If I just set canvas to z = -1 in the css file there aren't any concerns?

Comment: z-index property is there for a reason, it can't always be bad practice I reckon! If it solves your problem and there is no other way of doing it (reorganising your HTML structure would be the other way if that is possible) then I wouldn't personally worry.

Comment: Okay awesome thanks for the help, if you make this (using the zIndex) property an answer I will accept it